# How to use a VCS behind a HTTP proxy?

Tags: svn, version-control, cvs, bazaar

How can I use a version control system behind a authenticating HTTP proxy. Note that I said "a VCS" , so it can be SVN, CVS , BAZAAR ... I've tried several SVN clients -- they do not work. It looks like BZR has an option for that , but I've seen no public mention of it. Help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the suggestions on the Subversion web site? [Link](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#proxy)

I've found that, if their suggestions don't work, It'll be just as hard getting any other VCS working.

What problems have you run into?

Comment: I configured SVN as the website says, but it still doesn't work. Do I need to specify anything else apart from the proxy address , port , username and password? Also , I think that the proxy I'm using only allows traffic through port 80 ...

Comment: Some more examination shows that SVN is going haywire trying to connect to 4XXX ports on the proxy (which I think the proxy does not allow). Can SVN work with only port 80?

Comment: First: Are you trying to get the client or the server working?
Second: If you're trying to use the client, could you post a sample of the URL you are using?
Third: If you're trying to use the server, I'd recommend using the Apache integration.

Answer (score 0):

In Bazaar, set the `HTTP_PROXY` or `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables with a command like:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://user@www.someproxy.com:3128
```

It should then prompt you for a password when you interact with remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the SVN client TortoiseSVN?  Click:

```
TortoiseSVN/Settings/Network
```

...and you can fill in your proxy settings, including username and password, if required.